# How to save files in pdf format?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

Recently I'm having trouble with my LibreOffice app. It seems that it doesn't support PDF format to save documents. Do you guys know any way around this problem? I looked around for converters and things like that but no luck. I also checked the help and support services with no luck. Got any solutions?
Thank you.

Comment: Where you attempting to use the drop-down menu option (in LibreOffice) or the icon ('Export Directly as PDF')?

Answer (score 31):

LibreOffice Writer > File > Export as PDF.

Then Click Export in the dialog box that just popped up.

Make sure that you are using the [latest version](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/).